# hyperref url overfull hbox: word is in an awkward place

Tags: hyperref, hyphenation, overfull

pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian)

I have

```
\begin{enumerate}[label={[\arabic*]}]
\item Alex McLean et al., \emph{Documentation Reference: Tidal Cycles}:
``Configuration; I/O (MIDI, OSC); OSC.'' Accessed April
26, 2023. [Online]. Available:
\url{http://tidalcycles.org/docs/configuration/MIDIOSC/osc/}
```

Because of the two-column layout (I cannot change that, it's mandated by the conference), the right margin occurs around here: MIDI|OSC.

Is there any way to force a line break somewhere in here, without losing the clickable link? Other URLs are breaking at word boundaries; this one is unique in that the margin is smack in the middle of a word.

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE community. What is your minimal complete code in tex format that you can add here?

Comment: Try loading the [xurl](https://ctan.org/pkg/xurl) package, in addition to the `hyperref` package.

Comment: xurl solved the problem, thanks!